# How to create POJO dynamically using JSON?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have multiple dyanamic json templates as belows

JSON 1

```
{
      "param1": "testuser1",
      "param2": "testuser1@gmail.com"
}
```

JSON 2

```
{
      "param1": "testuser2",
      "param2": "testuser2@gmail.com",
      "param3": "New York"
}
```

JSON 3

```
{
      "param1": "testuser3"
      "param2": "testuser3@gmail.com",
      "param3": "New York",
      "param4": [
            {
                "sub-param1": "X",
                "sub-param2": "Y"
            },
            {
                "param1": "testuser",
                "param2": "testuser@gmail.com"
            }
          ]
}
```

I want to covert them into JAVA Object at runtime i.e. without creating POJO at compile time. Is this possible ? If yes how to do that?

I tried using Jackson lib to convert json into object (Object Class), but how to create common generic POJO or how to create POJO with setter getter dynamically?

Comment: Why can't you use JsonNode class?

Comment: yeah the idea is that we don't know content of json.

Comment: That's kinda the point of using the JsonNode and JsonObject classes

Comment: If you don't mind using external library, you can have a look at [jsonschema2pojo][1] 


  [1]: https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/wiki/Getting-Started#using-jsonschema2pojo-within-your-java-project-embedded

Comment: how are you supposed to access the fields in this POJO if the _users_ of the object _at compile time_ don't know what fields exist in it?

Comment: I think  can access fields of this pojo using reflection

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to deserialize your JSON document into a `Map<String, Object>` or maybe use the Jackson tree model, as shown below:

```java
TypeReference<Map<String, Object>> type = new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {};
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, type);
```

```java
JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
```

Comment: @user12290051 Why do you think you need to create a class dynamically?

Comment: Actually I am using smooks framework to create edi file from json,but smooks framework says to have POJO defined while converting to edi or any other format. I created one example that convert json to edi but I want dynamic json file to be converted into edi. So I was searching whether I can do this ? I tried reflection but no luck

Comment: @user12290051 Have you tried the map approach described above?

Comment: Yeah I tried it thanks but how to use this in smooks need to check..